# MongoDB multiple counts, single document, arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been searching on stackoverflow and cannot find exactly what I am looking for and hope someone can help.  I want to submit a single query, get multiple counts back, for a single document, based on array of that document.

My data:

```
db.myCollection.InsertOne({
  "_id": "1",
  "age": 30,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "isSuccessful": true,
      "name": null
    },{
      "id": "2",
      "isSuccessful": true,
      "name": null
    },{
      "id": "3",
      "isSuccessful": true,
      "name": "Bob"
    },{
      "id": "4",
      "isSuccessful": null,
      "name": "Todd"
    }
  ]
});

db.myCollection.InsertOne({
  "_id": "2",
  "age": 22,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "6",
      "isSuccessful": true,
      "name": "Jeff"
    }
  ]
});
```

What I need back is the document and the counts associated to the items array for said document.  In this example where the document _id = "1":

```
{
  "_id": "1", 
  "age": 30,
  {
    "totalIsSuccessful" : 2,
    "totalNotIsSuccessful": 1,
    "totalSuccessfulNull": 1,
    "totalNameNull": 2
  }
}
```

I have found that I can get this in 4 queries using something like this below, but I would really like it to be one query.

```
db.test1.aggregate([
  { $match : { _id : "1" } },
  { "$project": {
    "total": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$items",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.isSuccessful", true ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count array elements that matches condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167692/count-array-elements-that-matches-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your expected result is invalid since you have an object literal in the middle of another object and also you have `totalIsSuccessful` for `id:1` as `2` where it seems they should be `3`. With that said ...

you can get similar output via `$unwind` and then grouping with `$sum` and `$cond`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: "1" } },
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  { $group: { 
    _id: "_id",
    age: { $first: "$age" },
    totalIsSuccessful: { $sum: { $cond: [{ "$eq": [ "$items.isSuccessful", true ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
    totalNotIsSuccessful: { $sum: { $cond: [{ "$ne": [ "$items.isSuccessful", true ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
    totalSuccessfulNull: { $sum: { $cond: [{ "$eq": [ "$items.isSuccessful", null ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
    totalNameNull: { $sum: { $cond: [ { "$eq": [ "$items.name", null ]}, 1, 0] } } }
  }
])
```

The output would be this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "_id",
    "age": 30,
    "totalIsSuccessful": 3,
    "totalNameNull": 2,
    "totalNotIsSuccessful": 1,
    "totalSuccessfulNull": 1
  }
]
```

You can [see it working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MkxFV28jLoq)