# Filter and count the number of element in an array

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongoDB I use query

```
db.getCollection('managements').find({'managers.role':"HR"},{'managers.$':1})
```

I get result as below

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "managers" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "100",
            "role" : "HR"
        },
        {
            "id" : "101",
            "role" : "ADMIN"
        },
        {
            "id" : "102",
            "role" : "ADMIN"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
    "managers" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "104",
            "role" : "ADMIN"
        },
        {
            "id" : "105",
            "role" : "HR"
        }
        ,
        {
            "id" : "106",
            "role" : "HR"
        }
        ,
        {
            "id" : "107",
            "role" : "HR"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to get individual count where role is HR, like

```
{id: 1
count : 1}
{ id:2
count : 3}
```

I tried using aggregate but gives me total count 4. I want individual count from result.

Comment: @Ashh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167692/count-array-elements-that-matches-condition solved it. How I can apply one more filter get where count is more than 1

Comment: Please ask a new question if you further doubts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59786240/5201420